# android command not found

Tags: 16.04, android, android-sdk

I am running ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed android-sdk using :-

```
sudo apt-get install android-sdk
```

and after installation , when i run

```
android
```

it says command not found.

I cannot even see "android-sdk" in my home folder.

When i run `sudo apt-get install android-sdk` command again , it says

```
android-sdk is already the newest version (24.3.3+2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I even tried finding "android" in my "/home/username" directory , "root" directory.

I cannot find it.

Comment: What is the output of `which android-sdk`?

Comment: blank no output

Comment: Which `ppa` did you add to install android-sdk?

Comment: Not a solution but might be interesting anyways:  consider installing the package `command-not-found` (Suggest installation of packages in interactive bash sessions) via `sudo apt install command-not-found`

Comment: @Raphael no ppa . I simply ran `sudo apt-get install android-sdk`

Comment: linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969753/android-command-not-found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Uninstall actual `android-sdk`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge android-sdk
  ```
- Download the latest android-sdk using:

  ```
  wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz
  ```
- Unpack downloaded package to your HOME directory:

  ```
  tar -xvf android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz
  ```
- Set `ANDROID_HOME` path

  - Open `.bashrc` file

    ```
    nano ~/..bashrc
    ```
  - Put these lines in the end of file

    ```
    export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$HOME/android-sdk-linux/tools:$HOME/android-sdk-linux/build-tools
    ```

    - Restart your computer to make changes

      Check also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps

Now you should able to use `android` command.

Try to update your sdk using:

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks. still works for ubuntu 18